# Bidirectional sub/resource relationships in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So there's this nifty thing I can do with my resource classes in Jax-RS:

```
@Path("/clubs")
class ClubsResource {
      @Path("/")
      @GET
      public Response getClubs() {
          // return list of clubs
      }

      @Path("/{id}")
      @GET
      public Response getClub(@PathParam("id") long id) {
          // return club with given id 
      }

     //lots of other club endpoints
}

@Path("/people")
class PeopleResource {
      @Path("/")
      @GET
      public Response getPeople() {
          // return list of people
      }

      @Path("/{id}")
      @GET
      public Response getPerson(@PathParam("id") long id) {
          // return person with id 
      }

       //THIS IS THE NIFTY PART         
      @Path("/{id}/clubs")
      public ClubsResource getClubStuffForPerson(@PathParam("id") long personId) {
          return new ClubsResource(personId);
      }
}
```

What's nifty about it is that it allows me to "extend" the `PeopleResource` with the `ClubsResource` - it gives me endpoints `/people/1234/clubs`, `/people/1234/clubs/5678`, and `people/1234/clubs/<every other ClubsResource endpoint>`, almost for free.

**I'd like to do something analogous to this in my angular application using ui-router**.

So I have:

```
$stateProvider
     .state('people', { 
          url: '/people'
      }).state('people.detail', { 
          url: '/{personId}' 

       //lots of other people states 

      }).state('clubs', { 
          url: '/clubs'
      }).state('clubs.detail', { 
          url: '/{clubId}'
      }).state('clubs.detail.edit', { 
          url: '/edit'
      })

      // lots of other clubs states
```

And I'd like to "extend" the `people.detail` state with all the `clubs.*` states (and vice versa): For instance, I want a `people.detail.clubs` state (at url `/people/1234/clubs`) that shows me all the clubs for person 1234. And a `clubs.detail.people` state at `/clubs/5678/people` that shows me all the people in club 5678.

Obviously I can create these states manually, but I'm wondering whether a  construct exists in ui-router that's analogous to that of sub-resource locators in Jax-RS, allowing me to do what I did there (as this would be far more maintainable given "clubs" and "people" states of arbitrary complexity).

**Update: As a hackish and incomplete way of achieving this**, I'm doing:

```
//people_states.js 

var list = {/* object-style definition of people list state */  };
var detail = {/* object-style definition of people detail state */  };

module.constant('PeopleStates', {
    list: function(customUrl){
        //param allows other states to use same definition with different URL
        var toReturn = angular.copy(list);
        toReturn.url = customUrl ? customUrl : toReturn.url; 
        return toReturn;
     }
    detail: function(url){/* same idea */ }
}


 //club_states.js 

 //var list, detail... same idea 

 module.constant('ClubStates', {/*same idea*/})

 module.config(function($stateProvider, PeopleStates, ClubStates){ 
      $stateProvider
          .state('clubs', ClubStates.list()) 
          .state('clubs.detail', ClubStates.detail()) 
          .state('clubs.detail.members', PeopleStates.list("/members"))                
          .state('clubs.detail.members.detail', PeopleStates.detail()) 
           //^^ so URL is /clubs/5678/members/1234             
 })
```

This helps me eliminate most of the code duplication, but feels pretty hacky and doesn't get to the heart of my question - which is whether ui-router provides a more elegant way of doing this natively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know this is not supported by `ui-router` out of the box, all `.state()` states have to be declared to be registered in `ui-router`. What is supported is that states are nested and all previous states must be resolved before entering child state.

I had similar problem with duplication of resolve functions in multiple states which I solved by abstracting it into a service similarly as you are doing.

In other project I also did a function which generated full state declarations (name, url, template, ctrl, resolve) based on some parmaeters because I was opening more like 20 slightly different modals as states :)

So in the end you abstract away generation of state definitions which is ok.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. That was my intuition, thanks for confirming.

Comment: No worries, hope it helped!